# Can a mobile phone receive signal on 868.4 MHz frequency?

Tags: android, ios

I have a device that transmits data over 868.4 MHZ frequency with GFSK modulation. I have read some articles and I think, that classic mobile phones can receive a signal on this frequency, if not please tell me.

Can I receive this signal with my phone and use the application in it to provide info about demodulation and make transmitted data readable on that device?

Thanks for answers.

Comment: I believe frequency range is dependent on make and model of the phone. This might help https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/59157/over-what-frequency-range-can-the-microphone-of-smartphone-receive-the-sound.

Comment: Even if it can receive that frequency, you generally won't have low-level access to the radio to receive arbitrary encoding on arbitrary frequencies.